# JBoss 7 webapp custom login module without modifying server configs

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I need to implement custom login module in JBoss 7. According to all documentation I have been able to dig up I need to modify server configs to define my custom login module. Is there any way to define a custom login module on per-WAR basis, without modifying server's standalone.xml / domain.xml?

It looks like this was possible in JBoss 6 and earlier, but I need it in JBOSSAS 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can define login modules in your war without any issues.

you should be adding configuration to jboss-web.xml

for example as

```
<jboss-web>  
  <security-domain>SPNEGO</security-domain>  
    <valve>  
        <class-name>org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator</class-name>  
    </valve>  
</jboss-web>
```

for more details see [security domain documentation](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SecurityDomainModel#jive_content_id_Deploying_Custom_Tomcat_Authenticators_in_AS7%20and) and [subsystem documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Security+subsystem+configuration)

Comment: I have perused JBOSS security docs, including the ones linked to above, and fail to see how I can configure custom login module on per-webapp basis without modifying either standalone.xml or domain.xml. The valve definition as per your answer only seems to activate a specific security domain - which still has to be defined in global server config. Can you please elaborate on your answer?